# Intersection and Union Probability Events

Tags: probability

In a certain suburb, 42% of families have a pet dog and 35% of families have a pet cat. Let  be the event
a family has a pet cat, and let  be the event a family has a pet dog. If 64% of families have a pet dog or
cat (or both), answer the following questions.

If a family has a pet cat, what is the probability the family has a pet dog?

I solved the problem with a Venn diagram, but I'm unsure of my final answer.
The entire diagram should be 64% of dogs and cats.

Therefore, the probability of just dogs, should be .64-.42 = .22
The probability of just cats, should be .64-.35 = .29

The probability of having both animals is therefore .64-(.22+.29) = .13

Is my math correct? I solved most of the problem visually with a Venn Diagram, so I would like to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your math checks okay.   Using a Venn diagram is perfectly reasonable for this level of question.   However, as you want to double check:

> In a certain suburb, 42% of families have a pet dog and 35% of families have a pet cat. Let  be the event a family has a pet cat, and let  be the event a family has a pet dog. If 64% of families have a pet dog or cat (or both), answer the following questions.

So we have, $\mathsf P(D)=0.42\,, \mathsf P(C)=0.35\,, \mathsf P(C\cup D)=0.64$

This tells us:  $\mathsf P(C\cap D^\complement)=\mathsf P(C\cup D)-\mathsf P(D) = 0.22,\\ \mathsf P(D\cap C^\complement)=\mathsf P(C\cup D)-\mathsf P(C)= 0.29$

Et cetera, and on topic:
 $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C\cap D) =~& \mathsf P(D)+\mathsf P(C)-\mathsf P(C\cup D) \\~=~& 0.42+0.35-0.64\\~=~& 0.13 & \color{green}{\checkmark}\\[2ex]\therefore\quad\mathsf P(D\mid C) ~=~& \dfrac {13}{35} \\ \approx~& 0.37{\small 1}\end{align}$$